# Python String filter

Tags: python, string, lambda, filter

I am trying to solve a class assignment as listed below

Use lambda expressions and the filter() function to filter out words from a list that don't start with the letter 's'. For example:

```
seq = ['soup','dog','salad','cat','great']
```

should be filtered down to:

```
['soup','salad']
```

I wrote the following two sets of code...

```
seq = ['soup', 'dog','salad', 'cat', 'great']
result = filter (lambda test: test[0] == "s",seq)
print (result)

seq = ['soup', 'dog','salad', 'cat', 'great']
def checkf (input):
    if input[0]=='s':
            a = "TRUE"
    return(a)
test = seq[0]
result = filter (checkf(test),seq)
print (result)
```

Both codes give a strange answer
filter object at 0x112aa06d8
as if it is returning a memory address in hexadecimal...
What's wrong?

Comment: I have edited your question to more appropriately reflect a more readable question see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further help in regards to asking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does foo = filter(...) return a <filter object>, not a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174276/why-does-foo-filter-return-a-filter-object-not-a-list)

Comment: In Python 3, `filter` returns a special filter object rather than a list. You can convert it to a list using the `list` function.

Comment: what is wrong with the first code. Works for me with python 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use filter, map, and reduce in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python 3, filter objects are iterators. To print the contents, you have to materialize it into a sequence first, so try:

```
print( list(result))
```

See also: [How to use filter, map, and reduce in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

To use lambda and filter to resolve this problem, you need to specify that the result of your code will be a list.

So the following will work:

```
seq = ['soup', 'dog','salad', 'cat', 'great']
list(filter (lambda test: test[0] == "s",seq))
```

or (assigning to an object):

```
seq = ['soup', 'dog','salad', 'cat', 'great']
result = list(filter (lambda test: test[0] == "s",seq))
print(result)
```

The result of the two codes will be:

```
['soup', 'salad']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the below code where your seq can be solved according to the lambda function.

```
seq = ['soup', 'dog','salad', 'cat', 'great']
result = list(filter (lambda test: test[0] == "s",seq))
print(result)
```

output: `['soup', 'salad']`

using it in a function

```
seq = ['soup', 'dog','salad', 'cat', 'great']
def check(input):
    result = list(filter (lambda test: test[0] == "s",seq))
    return result

check(seq)
```

output: `['soup', 'salad']`