# Filter a list containing specific string

Tags: python, list

**My Goal**

I have a specific set of a long list containing many asset pairs with different endings: `BTCUSDT` `ETHBTC` `ANKRETH`... From this list, I would like to filter out the symbols ending with USDT.

**My Problem:**

I have tried using `filter` and `all` with iterations, however, none provides the exact result.

Here are my attempts:

**Attempt 1:**

```
my_set = ['LUNAUSDT', 'ETHBTC', 'ETHBNB', 'BTCUSDT', 'MANATUSD', 'ALICEETH' ]
my_set = [word for word in symbols if 'USDT' in my_set]
my_set
```

> This results in an empty set.

**Attempt 2:**

```
keyword = ['USDT']
my_set = ['LUNAUSDT', 'ETHBTC', 'ETHBNB', 'BTCUSDT', 'MANATUSD', 'ALICEETH' ]
final = [ x for x in my_set in all(keyword in keyword for keyword in my_set)]
final
```

This results in the error:

> TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

**Attempt 3:**

```
my_final_set = filter(lambda x:x.endswith(("USDT")), my_set)
my_final_set
```

> This shows: <filter at 0x7fe537eebf10>

I basically want my final list with all symbols ending with `USDT`

**For example:**

```
my_set = ['LUNAUSDT', 'ETHBTC', 'ETHBNB', 'BTCUSDT', 'MANATUSD', 'ALICEETH' ]
```

results in: `['LUNAUSDT', 'BTCUSDT']`

Any help or advice on what I'm doing wrong would be massively appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Try this:

```
my_set = ['LUNAUSDT', 'ETHBTC', 'ETHBNB', 'BTCUSDT', 'MANATUSD', 'ALICEETH' ]
final = [word for word in my_set if 'USDT' in word]
print(final)
```

For your **Attempt 3**, make this change:

```
my_final_set = list(filter(lambda x:x.endswith(("USDT")), my_set))
```

One another method is to use `.endswith()`:

```
final = [word for word in my_set if word.endswith('USDT')]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
['LUNAUSDT', 'BTCUSDT']
```

Answer (score 3):

##### Attempt 1

> ```
> [word for word in symbols if 'USDT' in my_set]
> ```

This has two mistakes:

- `'USDT' in my_set` checks if `'USDT'` is contained in the input list, not if it is contained in *one of the words* from the input list. You should have used `'USDT' in word`.
- `'USDT' in word` would check if `'USDT'` is contained *anywhere* in `word` (not just at the end). In order to check if a string *ends with* a particular suffix, use `word.endswith('USDT')`.

##### Attempt 2

> ```
> [ x for x in my_set in all(keyword in keyword for keyword in my_set)]
> ```

This makes the least sense of your attempts. `all(...)` returns either `True` or `False`, depending on whether a condition is true for all elements from an iterable. In this case `keyword in keyword` is obviously true for all words `keyword` from `my_set`, so this would be equivalent to

```
[x for x in my_set in True]
```

Here, Python would try to evaluate `my_set in True` as if `True` were some sort of collection. It attempts this by trying to iterate over `True` (and then checking in turn if any item is equal to `my_set`), which is not possible.

##### Attempt 3

> ```
> filter(lambda x:x.endswith(("USDT")), my_set)
> ```

This is mostly correct, however `filter` returns an *iterator*, which only returns the results as you iterate over it. In order to get a list, you have to consume the iterator:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith(("USDT")), my_set))
```

which is approximately equivalent to

```
result = []
for y in filter(lambda x: x.endswith(("USDT")), my_set):
    result.append(y)
```

See [Why does foo = filter(...) return a <filter object>, not a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174276/why-does-foo-filter-return-a-filter-object-not-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

solution using `filter` function and `list-comprehension`

```
my_set = ['LUNAUSDT', 'ETHBTC', 'ETHBNB', 'BTCUSDT', 'MANATUSD', 'ALICEETH' ]
keyword = 'USDT'

result1 = list(filter(lambda word: word.endswith(keyword), my_set))
result2 = [ word for word in my_set if word.endswith(keyword)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
import re

my_set = ['LUNAUSDT', 'ETHBTC', 'ETHBNB', 'BTCUSDT', 'MANATUSD', 'ALICEETH' ]

my_filtered_set = [ i for i in my_set if re.search('USD$',i) ]
```