# Filter List of T or list of some type in Python

Tags: python, list, filter

I am new to Python. I have a List of T i.e. List of PackageReference objects. The PackageReference object is defined as follows:

```
class PackageReference:
    def __init__(self, ecosystem, repository_root, repository_name, source, package_name, version):
        self.ecosystem = ecosystem
        self.repository_root = repository_root
        self.repository_name = repository_name
        self.source = source
        self.package_name = package_name
        self.version = version
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'PackageReference({self.ecosystem} {self.package_name} {self.version} {self.repository_name} {self.source})'
```

Now I am fetching a list of PackageReference items on which I want to apply a filter. The filter condition is, I want all the items where the ecosystem=='NuGet'. In C# you would do something like `list.Where(x=>x.ecosystem=="NuGet")`. I am trying to do the filter like this in Python but after I apply the filter, the list is empty.

```
package_references = collect_package_references(patterns, commits, rules)

# Filter the packages based on criteria
filtered_list=filter(lambda item:item.ecosystem=='NuGet',package_references) #The filtered_list is empty.
```

Before filter as I am debugging this is the screenshot of the package_references.

[image: package_references list]

Upon setting breakpoint on filtered_list= line, it shows me the following:

[image: result]

Comment: That should work. Note that `filter()` doesn't return a list, it returns a generator, you need to iterate over it to get the values.

Comment: If you want a list, use `list(filter(...))` or a list comprehension `[item for item in package_rererences if item.ecosystem == 'NuGet']`

Comment: Thank you so much. I wanted a list and adding a list(filter....)) works fine.

Comment: The list comprehension is considered more pythonic.

Comment: I see, coming from the C# world, I kind of like the list(filter....))  more  :)

Comment: When in Rome....

Comment: `filter()` and some other similar functions return a iterator and you are likely expecting a proper list. You can exercise the iterator getting it to return all items to you via `filtered_list = list(filtered_list)`.  In the future you might check out some related concepts such as `next()`, `iter()`, and `yield`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does foo = filter(...) return a <filter object>, not a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174276/why-does-foo-filter-return-a-filter-object-not-a-list)